Not supported URL scheme http+docker when building the sonic project
During the building, I got the error like:
+sudo LANG=C DOCKER_HOST= chroot ./fsroot-ot-vs /usr/local/bin/generate_shutdown_order.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 633, in send
conn = self.get_connection_with_tls_context(
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 489, in get_connection_with_tls_context
conn = self.poolmanager.connection_from_host(
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/urllib3/poolmanager.py", line 304, in connection_from_host
return self.connection_from_context(request_context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/urllib3/poolmanager.py", line 326, in connection_from_context
raise URLSchemeUnknown(scheme)
urllib3.exceptions.URLSchemeUnknown: Not supported URL scheme http+docker
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 214, in _retrieve_server_version
return self.version(api_version=False)["ApiVersion"]
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/docker/api/daemon.py", line 181, in version
return self._result(self._get(url), json=True)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/docker/utils/decorators.py", line 46, in inner
return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 237, in _get
return self.get(url, **self._set_request_timeout(kwargs))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 602, in get
return self.request("GET", url, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 589, in request
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 703, in send
r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 637, in send
raise InvalidURL(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.InvalidURL: Not supported URL scheme http+docker
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/generate_shutdown_order.py", line 15, in 
main()
File "/usr/local/bin/generate_shutdown_order.py", line 8, in main
manager = PackageManager.get_manager()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/sonic_package_manager/manager.py", line 1029, in get_manager
docker_api = DockerApi(docker.from_env(), ProgressManager())
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/docker/client.py", line 96, in from_env
return cls(
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/docker/client.py", line 45, in init
self.api = APIClient(*args, **kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 197, in init
self._version = self._retrieve_server_version()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 221, in _retrieve_server_version
raise DockerException(
docker.errors.DockerException: Error while fetching server API version: Not supported URL scheme http+docker
+clean_sys
I see the DOCKER_HOST is empty, does this cause by the empty DOCKER_HOST? How to set a proper DOCKER_HOST variable? Thanks in advance.
